# Google Actions Smart Home Air Conditioning Unit Can Not Temperature Setting

Tags: google-home

My google actions SYNC response is..

```
{
  "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
  "payload": {
    "agentUserId": "1836.15267389",
    "devices": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "action.devices.types.AC_UNIT",
        "traits": [
          "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
          "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting"
        ],
        "name": {
          "name": "AC",
          "nicknames": [
            "AC"
          ]
        },
        "willReportState": false,
        "attributes": {
          "availableThermostatModes": "off,heat,cool,on",
          "thermostatTemperatureUnit": "C"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I told google mini to set the AC temperature.

**Then google replied that this instruction is not supported.**

But turn on/off is working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where's your code that tries to set the AC temperature?

Comment: I told google mini that when setting the temperature, he did not send the API to my server.

Comment: If your question is not about code, it's off topic here. Did you write code for Google Mini? If not, we can't help you.

Comment: [Smart Home TemperatureSetting Trait Schema](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/temperaturesetting.html)

I follow this page to set up the google actions,but I can not control the temperature

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't see any code that tries to set the temperature and fails. Where is that code? If there is no code that tries to set the temperature, then this is the wrong site for your question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Because in addition to the "SYNC" "QUERY" command,

I did not receive the "EXECUTE" command from google.

Answer (score 0):

Use action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT

can fix the issue